# NVelocity -- #parse with embedded resources

Tags: nvelocity

I'm generating emails based off embedded NVelocity templates and would like to do something with dynamically included sections.  So my embedded resources are something like this:

DigestMail.vm
_Document.vm
_ActionItem.vm
_Event.vm

My email routine will get a list of objects and will pass each of these along with the proper view to DigestMail.vm:

```
public struct ItemAndView
{
    public string View;
    public object Item;

}

private void GenerateWeeklyEmail(INewItems[] newestItems)
{
    IList<ItemAndView> itemAndViews = new List<ItemAndView>();
    foreach (var item in newestItems)
    {
        itemAndViews.Add(new ItemAndView
        {
            View = string.Format("MyAssembly.MailTemplates._{0}.vm", item.GetType().Name),
            Item = item
        });
    }

    var context = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    context["Recipient"] = _user;
    context["Items"] = itemAndViews;

    string mailBody = _templater.Merge("MyAssembly.MailTemplates.DigestMail.vm", context);
}
```

And in my DigestMail.vm template I've got something like this:

```
#foreach($Item in $Items)
====================================================================
#parse($Item.viewname)
#end
```

But it's unable to #parse when given the path to an embedded resource like this.  Is there any way I can tell it to parse each of these embedded templates?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jake, is .viewname a property?  I'm not seeing you setting it in your code, how about you use the following:

```
#foreach($Item in $Items) 
==================================================================== 
$Item.viewname
#end
```

I don't know why you're parsing the $Item.viename rather than just using the above?  I'm suggesting this as I've just never needed to parse anything!

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940126/nvelocity-not-finding-the-template) post where we've discussed the generation of templates.

Hope this helps!